# create a dense matrix from a spark dataset in Java

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, pca

Need some pointers on how to create a dense matrix from a dataset..

Say my dataset is a csv file with data row-1: 1.1,1.0,1.2 and row-2: 1.4,1.1,1.3
How to convert the dataset to a matrix..so that matrix operations can be applied.

Java/Spark

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use vectorassember. It is a feature transformer that merges multiple columns into a vector column
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler

```
val dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
  Seq((0, 18, 1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 10.0, 0.5), 1.0))
).toDF("id", "hour", "mobile", "userFeatures", "clicked")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("hour", "mobile", "userFeatures"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val vd= assembler.transform(dataset)
```